# Is it possible to detect being inside of a chrome app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have written a chrome extension that should embed itself on most pages; however, chrome applications (such as slack, google hangouts, etc.) still have my extension embedded on the page.

Is it possible to detect that I am running inside a chrome app (or, basically, anywhere that chrome defaults to not showing a website url) via javascript so I can not embed my script?

Comment: What are your host permissions? `"<all_urls>"`? Are you talking about regular app pages, and not simply `<webview>` embeds?

Comment: Currently I'm using <all_urls> because I want to embed it on every normal web pages. I'm not sure the difference and need to look up to answer the webview embed.

Comment: If http/https exhaust your definition of normal web pages, you can try with `"*://*/*"` permission instead. Though the question is interesting as-is. Have you tried looking at the URL of app windows from the content script?

Comment: Unfortunately, things like slack and hangouts actually have urls -- their url is stuff like https://company.slack.com, or hangouts.google.com/id

Comment: Have you looked at adding an `exclude_matches` property to your manifest file? You will need to explicitly list all of the chrome app URL's that you want to avoid, but it should work.

Comment: I am looking for a more generic solution to exclude all chrome apps. Given that I can also choose to kill my content script based on information accessible in the javascript, I am thinking that that approach is my best bet.

Comment: Your use of the informal term "chrome applications" might cause your question to be confused with one about Chrome Apps, which are very specific things. I suggest you remove the google-chrome-app tag. (Chrome Extensions never run inside Chrome Apps.)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the chrome ecosystem; so in the chrome web store, I download apps like 'Slack', which can run in their own window on a desktop; this shows up in my chrome://apps page. I thought this meant this was a chrome app, but could be wrong. I am looking to make sure that I do not run inside those apps.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check the existence (and that is not empty) of chrome.runtime.id:

```
if (window.chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id) {
    // Here you know that the code is running in a Chrome extension
}
```